# after_commit :on: :destroy in set_callback way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, call

I am using set callback and skip callback. Can I put multiple condition in it like

```
Model.set_callback(after_commit :do_this, on: :destroy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in an :if option and add your conditionals in there.
So this will be something like:

```
Model.set_callback(after_commit :do_this, on: :destroy, if: :condition)
```

> :if - A symbol, a string or an array of symbols and strings, each
>   naming an instance method or a proc; the callback will be called only
>   when they all return a true value

So as long as your instance method or proc is evaluating back to a true/false, you can put as many conditionals in it as you see fit.

(For reference also see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set_callback)